# Delete function works but sends error message

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been using this function to erase certain rows depending on the name of a cell in a column, for some reason it works, but after it finishes it just gives me an error message.

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id #################################################.

```
function erase() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = 'J:J';
  var object = 'Delete';
  var name = 'Roster';
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(name);
  var row = sheet.getRange(range);
  var value = row.getValues();
  for (var i = value.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (value[0, i] == object)
      sheet.deleteRow(i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This looks to be a known issue from Google's side which has been reported on Issue Tracker**. I suggest you star the issue from [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156530211) and eventually add a comment saying that you are affected by it.

*As a possible workaround*, you can try adding `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` before this line here `var row = sheet.getRange(range);`.

Comment: still havent been able to make it work, only answer to the bug report is that i need to confirm the trigger when that already has been done, since this is a function of other functions, and i even got other triggers setted up for this one

perhaps anyone would know any other way to make this script? that would be usefull too

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with google sheets specifically, but just with general syntax knowledge, I feel like the issue would surround, `var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`. Are you sure you arn't supposed to put anything inside the getActiveSreadshee(-here-)??